# How can I print the p-value with 2 significant figures?

Tags: r

When I print my p value from my t.test by doing:

```
ttest_bb[3]
```

It returns the full p value. How can I make it so it only prints the first two integers? i.e. `.03` instead of `.034587297`?

Comment: you may use `round(x, 2)` to get x printed with 2 decimals

Comment: That's not working for me! I tried round(ttest_bb[3],2) but I got: non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Comment: Did you try `round(ttest_bb[3], 2)`?

Comment: If that doesn't work, inspect `str(ttest_bb[3])` and see what it is.

Comment: yes, same result

Comment: `round(as.numeric(ttest_bb[3]), 2)`, and please, do what @RuiBarradas suggests.

Comment: round(as.numeric(ttest_bb[3]), 2) worked like a charm! thank you

Answer (score 1):

The output from t.test is a list.  If you only use `[` to grab the p-value then what is returned is a list with one element.  You want to use `[[` to grab the element contained at the spot in the list returned by t.test if you want to treat it as a vector.

```
> ttest_bb <- t.test(rnorm(20), rnorm(20))
> ttest_bb

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  rnorm(20) and rnorm(20)
t = -2.5027, df = 37.82, p-value = 0.01677
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.4193002 -0.1498456
sample estimates:
 mean of x  mean of y 
-0.3727489  0.4118240 

> # Notice that what is returned when subsetting like this is
> # a list with the name p.value
> ttest_bb[3]
$`p.value`
[1] 0.01676605
> # If we use the double parens then it extracts just the vector contained
> ttest_bb[[3]]
[1] 0.01676605
> # What you're seeing is this:
> round(ttest_bb[3])
Error in round(ttest_bb[3]) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function

> # If you use double parens you can use that value
> round(ttest_bb[[3]],2)
[1] 0.02
> # I prefer using the named argument to make it more clear what you're grabbing
> ttest_bb$p.value
[1] 0.01676605
> round(ttest_bb$p.value, 2)
[1] 0.02
```